# Is it possible to get Image elements to render in the XAML designer for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2019

I can no longer see the images that are bound to XAML  elements during design-time *only* in Visual Studio 2019. The same exact code displays the images properly in the Visual Studio 2017 designer.

Does anyone know if there is a setting or technique to get images to be rendered in 2019? Or know if this is perhaps a new "bug" or "feature"?

I do use XAML hot-reload. But certain elements of my UI rely on layout around images of certain widths and heights and it's just much easier to stage changes in the designer when a representative image is displayed.

Comment: Do you try to use  the [Pack URIs in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) to load image resource? Like  _Source="pack://application:,,,/imgss/Gakuse-Folder.ico"_    It is difficult to detect the reason that cause this problem. You may can share more related code.

Comment: I'm binding to an ImageSource in a ViewModel. The imagesource is, in fact, loaded from a URI in the code that instantiates the design-time viewmodel. Again, the exact same code is working in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/809662/xaml-images-bound-to-imagesource-not-loading-in-vi.html). Fixed and pending release.

Answer (score -1):

If you loaded image from a URI in the code that instantiates the design-time viewmodel. It will not display the image in the Visual Studio designer.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ImagesDetailsviewmodel/>
</Window.DataContext>

  <Image x:Name="image" Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="100" Source="{Binding ImaUrlName}" Width="100"/>

 public class ImagesDetailsviewmodel
{
    public ImagesDetailsviewmodel()
    {
        imaUrlName = "pack://application:,,,/imagess/test001.jpg";
    }

    private string imaUrlName;
    public string ImaUrlName
    {
        get
        {
            return imaUrlName;
        }
        set
        {
            imaUrlName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the xaml code directly to display image in the designer.

```
  <Image x:Name="image22" Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="100" Source="pack://application:,,,/imagess/test002.jpg" Width="100"/>
```

['Write and debug running XAML code with XAML Hot Reload in Visual Studio'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload?view=vs-2019) can help you to change  the XAML code when run your app.

Besides, you can share more related information and go to the [Developer Community Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) and report your issue.

Comment: Yes, this is basically confirming what I said in my original question. It doesn't so much good to have a static image path in my XAML. I have submitted a case to Visual Studio Developer Community as suggested and will update here if there are any developments.